Linear Interpolation in (Kdb+/ Q)
I have a pivoted table in Kdb+ with columns state, callable, matureyear, couponrate and rating columns. Rating columns are AAA, AA+, AA, AA- which are pivoted columns with yield as values.
State column has data types symbol and values as states CA, TX, NY, etc.
Callable column has data types symbol and values Y or N.
Couponrate column has data types float and values values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.
Matureyear column has data types j (long) and values values 1, 2, 3,…,30.
AAA, AA+, AA and AA- columns have yield values and float as the data type.
Data:



State
Callable
Couponrate
Matureyear
AAA
AA+
AA
AA-




MA
Y
1
2

4.34




CA
N
5
5



4.64


TX
Y
3
10
4.24





PA
N
4
5


4.34



NY
N
5
5



4.64


TX
N
5
10
4.24






I want to fill the missing values for columns AAA, AA+, AA, AA- for the each distinct group (state + callable + couponrate) for matureyear 0 to 30.
I have tried to generate possible combinations of all distinct group.
// Generate all possible combinations of matureyear (0 to 30) for each group 
maxYear: 30; 
uniqueKeys: distinct select state, callable, couponrate from data; 
    
// Create a table with all possible combinations 
//    of state, callable, couponrate, and matureyear
allMatureYears:raze {x cross enlist each til maxYear + 1} each uniqueKeys;
allMatureYears: (allMatureYears[`state];
                 allMatureYears[`callable];
                 allMatureYears[`couponrate]; 
                 allMatureYears[`matureyear]);

However, kdb throws the ‘type error in the cross function.

Can you resolve the formatting issues? Difficult to read the question as is.

allMatureYears:distinct select state, callable, couponrate from data;
allMatureYears:update matureyear:count[i]#enlist til maxYear + 1 from allMatureYears
allMatureYears:ungroup allMatureYears
allMatureYears: value flip allMatureYears


Thanks @rianoc, this helps create a table with all possible combinations.
